# Why isn't Opencv-python showing my camera feed?

Tags: python, opencv

Ok so I wanted to open my webcam feed in opencv python. When I run the code, it opens up a blank window and later says "Python has stopped working."I want to know why is it happening and how do I solve it !!!!
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using Spyder which I installed from Anaconda. I also tried the same code on jupyter notebook and also on the original python 3.8 software. The results were same.Here is an image of what I am facing:[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKCzO.png). For any clarification...please comment!!!

Comment: Try saving the script as `script.py` and running it in your Terminal with `python3 script.py`

Comment: It says  'python3 is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file'...how do i solve that ??

Comment: Maybe your Python interpreter needs `python script.py` - it depends how/where it was installed, but try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem....apparently it was the issue of the camera and not of the compiler/code. I changed my camera..it works now

Answer (score 0):

No problem with the code . Make sure you have a webcam in which you are running the program.

```
cv2.VideoCapture(index)
```

The **index** in videoCapture   indicates video capturing device to open. To open default camera 0 is used.

Comment: Yes...I do have a webcam attached to the computer in which i am using the program. Still the error occurs !!

Comment: Try with index 1

Comment: Yep tried that too

Comment: I assume that you already tried some other indexes. You may reinstall opencv-python or there may be problem with your Python interpreter.

Comment: So can i solve it by re-installing python ??